# How to fetch data of email parameters, just buy using a button and save it on a skim table, using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html-email, skim

How to fetch data of email parameters, just buy using a button and save it on a skim table, using Javascript?

Please help with fetching the data and then saving it to a skim table using a button

Comment: So, after a click from an email, it's going to a website? (And what's a "skim" table?)

Comment: Consider editing your question to include the JavaScript and HTML that you have been attempting to fix.